# "Deprecated" error migrating blog from blogger to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, blogger, migrate

I've migrated my old blog from Blogger to Wordpress. It's worked but I've received the following error:
"Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Blogger_Importer has a deprecated constructor in /home/melsiepa/public_html/wp-content/plugins/blogger-importer/blogger-importer.php on line 44"

I'm new to web so I have NO CLUE what to do / change!

This is line 44: class Blogger_Importer extends WP_Importer {

Here is the code in context:

```
 /**
     * Blogger Importer class for managing the import process of a XML 
    file
     *
 */
if ( !class_exists( 'Blogger_Importer' ) ) {
class Blogger_Importer extends WP_Importer {
    const IMPORT_IMG = true;         // Should we import the images (boolean)
    const LARGE_IMAGE_SIZE = '1024'; //
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should not change anything(code-wise), the warning that you have received is informing you that the coding of that certain file is using coding for a lower php version. To not see it I would suggest to try lowering the php version that your Wordpress site is currently using and once you are done using the 'blogger-importer' plugin to disable it and change the php version to a higher one.

- Would suggest to try lowering to 5.6 then to 5.4 or even 5.2 if you still see the warning*

If you encounter any issues performing the necessary steps write back and we will try to assist you.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you SO much for your help!!